# Reset navigation Parameters when navigating away ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Im trying to clear the parameters set by another page so that when I navigate from anywhere else in the application the parameters will reset, currently what Im doing is not working

Competitionspage:

```js
    const competitions =
    fireBaseCompetitionData &&
    fireBaseCompetitionData.map((i, index) => (
      <CompetitionCard
        {...i}
        key={index}
        navigation={() => enterCompetition(i.competitionName)}
      />
    ));
```

EnterCompetitionPage

```js
  const [category, setCategory] = useState(route.params)
  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      setValues({ ...values, competition: category });      
      console.log('focused');
      const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("blur", () => {
        setValues({ ...values, competition: "" });
        console.log(route.params)
        
      });
      
  
      return () => {
        unsubscribe();
        // const reset = CommonActions.reset({
        //   index: 0,
        //   actions: [
        //       CommonActions.navigate( 'Enter')
        //   ]
        // This wasn't working either })
    
      };
    }, [category])
  );
```

Navigation function

```js
  const enterCompetition = (category) => {
    navigation.navigate("Enter", { category: category });
  };
```